# Pass Variable On Import

Tags: python, import

Let's say you have some time-consuming work to do when a module/class is first imported.  This functionality is dependent on a passed in variable.  It only needs to be done when the module/class is loaded.  All instances of the class can then use the result.

For instance, I'm using rpy2:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = ## I need to pass this
robjects.r.source(PATH_TO_R_SOURCE, chdir = True) ## this takes time

class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, aCurve):
    self._curve = aCurve

  def processCurve(self):
    robjects.r['someRFunc'](robjects.FloatVector(self._curve))
```

Am I stuck creating a module level function that I call to do the work?

```
import someClass
someClass.sourceRStuff(PATH_TO_R_SOURCE)
x = someClass.SomeClass([1,2,3,4])
etc...
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Having a module init function isn't unheard of. Pygame does it for the sdl initialization functions. So yes, your best bet is probably

```
import someModule
someModule.init(NECESSARY_DATA)
x = someModule.someClass(range(1, 5))
```

Comment: any info on how to setup the init function in the module? is this the same as an \_\_init\_\_.py file? it doesn't appear so based on what you have written above. is this possible if you just have regular functions in your module and not classes?

Comment: This is not like an `__init__.py` file. The init function in the example is just an ordinary function that initializes the global state in the module.

Comment: could not find a good link describing the init method. Could you share one link describing how module init works. Thanks!

Comment: @NightFurry: It's not a special technique or something. It's just a function in the module that you call once at the beginning of your program. You can put a call to it when the module's loaded if appropriate, but it's really just an ordinary function.

Answer (score 27):

I had to do something similar for my project. If you don't want to rely on the calling script to run the initialization function, you can add your own Python builtin which is then available to all modules at runtime.

Be careful to name your builtin something unique that is unlikely to cause a namespace collision (eg `myapp_myvarname`).

run.py

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.myapp_PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = 'path.to.r.source'
import someClass
```

someClass module .py

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import __builtin__

if hasattr(__builtin__, "myapp_PATH_TO_R_SOURCE"):
    PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = __builtin__.myapp_PATH_TO_R_SOURCE
else:
    PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = ## Some default value or Null for Exception handling
robjects.r.source(PATH_TO_R_SOURCE, chdir = True)

...
```

This works well for variables that may have a default but you want to allow overriding at import time. If the `__builtin__` variable is not set, it will use a default value.

**Edit:** Some consider this an example of "Monkey patching". For a more elegant solution without monkey patch, [see my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39360070/1134080).

Comment: Thank you! This is useful for modules that execute code **during import** and you want to set the variables necessary for that execution. An `init` function is not helpful in that case, as `init` can only be called after the import is done.

Comment: This worked for me, but with python 3, needed to `import builtin`

Comment: I'm really liking this! For me, with Python 3, I needed to use builtins (plural) but then it worked just as @Aaron D explained it with __builtin__

Answer (score 19):

If there is only one configuration item to set, then I have found overriding the python `__builtin__` to work just fine, but it is an example of ["Monkey patching"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) which is frowned on by some.

A cleaner way to do it which is very useful for multiple configuration items in your project is to create a separate Configuration module that is imported by your wrapping code first, and the items set at runtime, before your functional module imports it. This pattern is often used in other projects.

**myconfig/__init__.py :**

```
PATH_TO_R_SOURCE   = '/default/R/source/path'
OTHER_CONFIG_ITEM  = 'DEFAULT'
PI                 = 3.14
```

**mymodule/__init__.py :**

```
import myconfig

PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = myconfig.PATH_TO_R_SOURCE
robjects.r.source(PATH_TO_R_SOURCE, chdir = True) ## this takes time

class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, aCurve):
    self._curve = aCurve

if myconfig.VERSION is not None:
  version = myconfig.VERSION
else:
  version = "UNDEFINED"

two_pi = myconfig.PI * 2
```

And you can change the behaviour of your module at runtime from the wrapper:

**run.py :**

```
import myconfig

myconfig.PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = 'actual/path/to/R/source'
myconfig.PI = 3.14159
# we can even add a new configuration item that isn't present in the original myconfig:
myconfig.VERSION="1.0"

import mymodule
print "Mymodule.two_pi = %r" % mymodule.two_pi
print "Mymodule.version is %s" % mymodule.version
```

**Output:**

```
> Mymodule.two_pi = 6.28318
> Mymodule.version is 1.0
```

Comment: This is also very nice! Much elegance. No monkeys. I hope you don't mind that I have edited your other answer to point a link to this one.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can simply create files called `myconfig.py` and `mymodule.py`. That would work just the same with less complexity. **Fun facts:** You can have `myconfig.py` completely blank. To check if variable is set, you can also use `try` with `except AttributeError` (unless you don't like using try-except for that kind of thing).

Answer (score 5):

Couple of other options that can achieve your goal (although a init() function is probably cleaner):

- Use an environment variable
- Use a separate module M to hold this variable, that the importer would set. Then the imported module could either know where to find M, or could rely on sys.meta_path to obtain it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to pass a variable at import.

Some ideas:

- make the module get the variable from the calling module using inspection; not very pythonic
- use an Init function for the module, this is the best way

Answer (score 2):

No you're not stuck with a module level function, it's just probably the best option. You could also use the builtin `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorators to make it a method on `someSclass` that can be called before it is instantiated.

This would make sense **only** if everything other than `someClass` was usable without the initialization and I still think a module level function is better.

Comment: The problem is when have modules can not use class, by example flask with blueprint, each controller only can functions not classes, can not encapsule the functionalities in classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions I can think of, both of which are very work-around-like solutions. The first is to ditch imports and run your script like this

```
sys.argv[1] = "argument 1"
sys.argv[2] = "argument 2"
execfile("/path/to/dependency.py")  #depreciated in python 3.x
```

The second is to put your arguments into an external temporary file, then read from that file in the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Could you benefit from a Proxy which implements lazy loading?

Check out the Active State "[Lazy Module Imports](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473888-lazy-module-imports/)" recipe.

Answer (score 0):

in any imported module you can do something like,

`if ___name__!="__main__":`
`import __main__ as mn`
`x=mn.x`

where you can use x as in the imported module, first by setting x in main,
also you can do something like mn.y=55 , so in main module after import you will be able to use y variable.