# python module __init__ function

Tags: python, module, initialization

Is there any way to make an implicit initializer for modules (not packages)?
Something like:

```
#file: mymodule.py
def __init__(val):
    global value
    value = 5
```

And when you import it:

```
#file: mainmodule.py
import mymodule(5)
```

Comment: Code placed in the "root" of a module (not in a function) will be run on import.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Global variables are usually a bad idea.

Comment: I can't place the code outside a function because I need to get arguments.
Basically I want the module to have a global variable that all the methods use, and it will be passed when I initialize the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Variable On Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720740/pass-variable-on-import)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `import` statement uses the [builtin `__import__` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__).
Therefore it's not possible to have a module `__init__` function.

You'll have to call it yourself:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.__init__(5)
```

Comment: It's totally unclear how how "builtin `__import__` function" and "impossibility to have `__init__` function" are connected. Even your own example shows that it's totally possible to have `__init__` function. But yeah, you'll need to call it yourself.

Comment: @pfalcon the question was looking for `import mymodule(5)` which is semantically impossible. Maybe my wording was a bit off five years ago. The connection is given with the fact, that there's no mechanism to configure a module with its import.

Answer (score 2):

These things often are not closed as duplicates, so here's a really nice solution from [Pass Variable On Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720740/pass-variable-on-import). TL;DR: use a config module, configure that before importing your module.

> [...] A cleaner way to do it which is very useful for multiple configuration
>   items in your project is to create a separate Configuration module
>   that is imported by your wrapping code first, and the items set at
>   runtime, before your functional module imports it. This pattern is
>   often used in other projects.
>
> **myconfig/__init__.py :**
>
> ```
> PATH_TO_R_SOURCE   = '/default/R/source/path'
> OTHER_CONFIG_ITEM  = 'DEFAULT'
> PI                 = 3.14
> ```
>
> **mymodule/__init__.py :**
>
> ```
> import myconfig
>
> PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = myconfig.PATH_TO_R_SOURCE
> robjects.r.source(PATH_TO_R_SOURCE, chdir = True) ## this takes time
>
> class SomeClass:
>   def __init__(self, aCurve):
>     self._curve = aCurve
>
> if myconfig.VERSION is not None:
>   version = myconfig.VERSION
> else:
>   version = "UNDEFINED"
>
> two_pi = myconfig.PI * 2
> ```
>
> And you can change the behaviour of your module at runtime from the
>   wrapper:
>
> **run.py :**
>
> ```
> import myconfig
>
> myconfig.PATH_TO_R_SOURCE = 'actual/path/to/R/source'
> myconfig.PI = 3.14159
> # we can even add a new configuration item that isn't present in the original myconfig:
> myconfig.VERSION="1.0"
>
> import mymodule
> print "Mymodule.two_pi = %r" % mymodule.two_pi
> print "Mymodule.version is %s" % mymodule.version
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> > Mymodule.two_pi = 6.28318
> > Mymodule.version is 1.0
> ```