# How to pass variable to imported script

Tags: python

I have few scripts where I multiplay some code and I started to do refractoring.
Below is the code which:

1) Create directory in the same place where the script is named log

2) Puts information into log/file_name.log

Below is the code:

```
    # Get path where script is
pathABSofScript = ""
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    pathABSofScript = str(os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 1)[0]) + "/"
else:
    print("Unknown operating system")
    exit(1)

if debug == "on":
    print("Absolute path for script: {0}".format(pathABSofScript))

# Create directory
directories = ['log']
for directory in directories:
    try:
        os.makedirs("{0}{1}".format(pathABSofScript, directory))
    except FileExistsError as ex:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting.".format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('{0}/log/scriptName.log'.format(pathABSofScript), maxBytes=1000000,
                                  backupCount=10)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info("Started")
As every my script has the same code I would like to create directory lib and call this code logger.py.
```

I have created directory structure as below:

```
scripts/
    lib/
        logger.py
    someScript/
        someScript.py
```

Previously in someScript directory script created log directory and then logged informations in someScript/log/someScript.log file.

When I have moved code to logger.py file making an import inside someScrip.py

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/me01/apps/onetick/apps/config-test/lib')
import logger
from logger import logger
```

the created log directory is inside lib/ directory instead of someScript/ - how to change that? I have tried to pass variable in someScript.py:

```
logger.pathABSofScript = "someScript/"
```

but it didn't worked.

How to pass variable to logger.py while importing it inside someScript.py?

Comment: PS . I have read similar topic and cannot find proper topic or I just simply don't understand the answers.

Answer (score 0):

similar answer is here:
[Pass Variable On Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720740/pass-variable-on-import) 
Basically, you have to create another folder, named "my_config" with 
`__init__.py` script in it.
So the structure of your project will be:

```
scripts/
    my_config/
        __init__.py
    lib/
        logger.py
    someScript/
        someScript.py
```

Then you have to put that code in `my_config/__init__.py` script:

```
PATH_TO_MY_SOURCE   = '/default/path'
```

Next, edit your lib/logger:

```
import my_config
PATH_TO_MY_SOURCE = my_config.PATH_TO_MY_SOURCE
...
```

Finally, in someScript.py:

```
import my_config
import os
my_config.PATH_TO_MY_SOURCE = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
from logger import logger
...
```

Comment: It would be better to configure config parser and place config.ini inside lib/ directory I think. Anyway thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alex-b for sharing his idea.
I have found another solution for that:

my logger.py looks like this:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import sys
import os
# IT IS NOT WORKING WITHOUT THIS LINE BELOW, DUNNO WHY
logger = None


def create_logger(path, file_name):
    global logger
    try:
        os.makedirs("{0}log".format(path))
    except FileExistsError as ex:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting.".format(
            type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('{0}log/{1}'.format(path, file_name), maxBytes=1000000,
                                      backupCount=10)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info("Started")


def info(msg):
    try:
        if isinstance(msg, str):
            logger.info(msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting."
                     .format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)


def debug(msg):
    try:
        if isinstance(msg, str):
            logger.debug(msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting."
                     .format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)


def warning(msg):
    try:
        if isinstance(msg, str):
            logger.warning(msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting."
                     .format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)


def error(msg):
    try:
        if isinstance(msg, str):
            logger.error(msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("An exception of typ {0} occurred in function {2}. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting."
                     .format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args, sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name))
        exit(1)
```

And I'm creating in my someScript.py

```
# pathABSofScript is gathered from someScript.py itself
logger.create_logger(pathABSofScript, "refresh.log")
logger.info("IT works!")
logger.warning("Warning test.")
```